# Mirror new HDD with old (raid 0) HDDs

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning, raid

So after fighting every day with my slow 3TBx2 Raided HDDs I decided to get a new one that's just 4TB (as I don't use more than 2TB currently).

It's a WD Black HDD that looks really promising. There's just one small problem.

I can't clone my current C: drive (Windows 7) as it's a raid 0 for 2 hard drive that also are encrypted.

Therefor live-CDs like [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) doesn't work. I've also tried [EaseUS Todo Backup](http://www.easeus.com/datarecoverywizard/free-data-recovery-software.htm) but that continuously fails.

I'd love some suggestions on what to do!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different cloning software, and since your new drive is WD you can try to clone the OS with Acronis True Image WD Edition:

http://products.wdc.com/support/kb.ashx?id=gWmfuO

Also, here's an article from our KB with the steps how to do it:

http://wdc.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/3682/~/how-to-manually-clone-a-disk-with-acronis-true-image-wd-edition-software

Let me know how it went. :)